# Leaflet Draw Plugin: How to draw polygon by one click?

Tags: android, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet in Android so I want to draw polygon by one click because it is too hard to draw by clicking two times to the same point on tablet.

I'm using Leaflet.draw plugin and this demo is working on browser perfectly and you can draw polygon on browser by one click.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/

But if I use the same demo on android, I have to click two times on the same point for drawing polygon.

This is not user friendly.

How can i do that ?

Sample code is shown below.

Note: I'm using cordova 2.9.0 for webview

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testdrawing;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        appView = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
        appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
        appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Leaflet.draw-master/examples/basic.html");

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



      <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
            android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Leaflet side was taken from [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) and I'm using basic.html example.**

**basic.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet.draw drawing and editing tools</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet.draw.css" />


    <script src="libs/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/Leaflet.draw.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Poly.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.SimpleShape.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Circle.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/Edit.Rectangle.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Feature.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Polygon.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.SimpleShape.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Rectangle.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Circle.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/draw/handler/Draw.Marker.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/ext/LatLngUtil.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/GeometryUtil.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/LineUtil.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/Polyline.Intersect.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/ext/Polygon.Intersect.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/Control.Draw.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Toolbar.js"></script>

    <script src="../src/draw/DrawToolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/EditToolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Edit.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/edit/handler/EditToolbar.Delete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>
    <button id="changeColor">Rectangle -> Blue</button>
    <script>
        var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18}),
            map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [cloudmade], center: new L.LatLng(-37.7772, 175.2756), zoom: 15 });


/*L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution : false,
                maxZoom : 18,
                crs : L.CRS.EPSG4326
                    }).addTo(map);*/
        var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
        map.addLayer(drawnItems);

        // Set the title to show on the polygon button
        L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.buttons.polygon = 'Draw a sexy polygon!';

        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            position: 'topleft',
            draw: {
                polyline: {
                    metric: true
                },
                polygon: {
                    allowIntersection: false,
                    showArea: true,
                    drawError: {
                        color: '#b00b00',
                        timeout: 1000
                    },
                    shapeOptions: {
                        color: '#bada55'
                    }
                },
                circle: {
                    shapeOptions: {
                        color: '#662d91'
                    }
                },
                marker: false
            },
            edit: {
                featureGroup: drawnItems,
                remove: false
            }
        });
        map.addControl(drawControl);

        map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;

            if (type === 'marker') {
                layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
            }

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        });

        map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
            var layers = e.layers;
            var countOfEditedLayers = 0;
            layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
                countOfEditedLayers++;
            });
            console.log("Edited " + countOfEditedLayers + " layers");
        });

        L.DomUtil.get('changeColor').onclick = function () {
            drawControl.setDrawingOptions({ rectangle: { shapeOptions: { color: '#004a80' } } });
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is just a "maybe" since I haven't been using cordova or any form of js implementations but try to `requestFocus();` on your webview. I'm thinking that the webview doesn't have focus as standard, and therefore has to be clicked twice, once for focus and once for the draw.